# Is it okay to use a non-ID column for foreign key reference?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have my tables as below

```
Role(Role ID, Name, Other_Columns)
Command(Command ID, Name, Other_Columns)
```

I have association table RoleCommand. Is it okay to have `RoleCommand(RoleName, CommandName)` instead of `RoleCommand(Role ID, Command ID)`. I feel like it is easier to read or populate the association table in this case if the names are used for reference. Please note, `RoleCommand` is populated manually with insert queries. There is no Web UI. I will setup unique key constraints and foreign key references on `Name` columns. Does anyone use this kind of references in production ? Most of the times I see only IDs being used for association tables.

UPDATE:

I am considering using `name` for foreign key references because the insert queries for `RoleCommand` are so ugly with nested `SELECT` queries inside `VALUES` to get the ID values from names. I don't want to just use IDs in the insert queries, to avoid errors.

Comment: make id a string instead

Comment: It's called a "Foreign ***Key***" for a reason...

Comment: @ErikEidt: yeah, it means that it's unique in the other table. I don't see how that helps with the question.

Answer (score 10):

- Using names as FKs is unorthodox at the least. Usually FKs point to the FK of the parent table.
- You might as well make `name` the PK of both tables and get rid of the `ID` altogether
- You've found one of the disadvantages of using surrogate PKs where good business keys exist. You should be able to read and understand the association table. **After all the data doesn't belong to the application, it belongs to the organization** (taken from another answer).

My recommendation is that if you've already decided to use surrogates, stick to them and point the FKs to them.

Also; if you created unique constraints on the names columns they are considered key columns so in theory you can point the FK to them but I find it inelegant.

Comment: I guess I am totally fine with using RoleName for primary key as well. Just thinking about cases when I ever rename the role..

Comment: Don't want to start a holy war, but it should be noted that this is also an advantage of surrogates: If you use business keys everywhere, and then your business requirements change (e.g. now we want to allow duplicates), you have to do an expensive multi-table schema change instead of a cheap constraint change.

Comment: +1, but also bear in mind there are good advantages for using the ID field (see, for example, DocBrown's answer to [this  question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254558/addressing-the-fact-that-primary-keys-are-not-part-of-your-business-domain)), so you need to weigh up the pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 7):

Your mistake is you want to use the `Name` instead of `ID` because `Name` is more Readable. What you should doing is making your `ID` more readable.

Think of it as `RoleCode` instead of `RoleID`

```
Role(RoleCode Pk, Name, Other_Columns)
Command(CommandID PK, RoleCode FK, Other_Columns)
```

*Sample Data*

```
RoleCode      Name              Other_Columns
--------      ----              -------------
Admin         Administrator
PwrUser       Power User
User          Standard User
```

Now your referential integrity is safe!

Comment: But when "Power User" needs to be changed to "Expert", would you really keep the RoleCode PwrUser?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: That's why a "Role" should have something like a "Name" or "DisplayText". The PK could be PowerUser, and then just change the Name or DisplayText to "Expert".

Answer (score 2):

YES, it is ok to use a non-ID column for foreign key reference unless and until it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it.

The basic definition of foreign key is : "Primary key in one table acting as a Foreign key in another table".
By standard SQL, the reference of a foreign key should be the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY in the referenced table.

If you can non-ID column as your primary keys, then that's good. However, there are some advantages of using ID column as a foreign key reference :

1. ID columns, especially those that are IDENTITYcolumns are also good as indexes (sometimes) in a sense that they almost never get updated, and if you don't delete rows from the table, you decrease index fragmentation.
2. When you don't have a create_date/entry_date column and you ever need to check data in the order they were entered.. having an ID column as an identity makes that possible.
3. While compound keys work, a single primary key can be sometimes be easier to work with. For instance, on doing deletes it is very easy to single out a particular row.
   It is also often more efficient to search on a numeric key.

Thank you !